# Restrict Laravel API access to given frontend(s) only

Tags: laravel

I'm using **Laravel** as API with **Passport** and *Password Grant Token*.

When no user is logged in, frontends still needs to access API routes to get misc data or to register a user. How should I protect these routes, used by a given frontend (set in `api.php`), to be only accessible by a frontend ?

Comment: You shouldn’t be using password grants. They’re disallowed entirely in OAuth’s security best practices: https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/password/

Comment: @MartinBean I'm using multiple providers, which is currently only available with Password Grant Token. This problem is discussed [here](https://github.com/laravel/passport/pull/1220#issuecomment-658792978). I hope this option can be extended to other part of Passport soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restrict access to your API in the `cors.php` configuration file. You can set which domains are allowed to access your API in the `allowed_origins` header. It's a very easy way to achieve this without much hassle.

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on how you are accessing the API. If you've created an app to access the API, for example, it would be impossible to truly restrict access to known domains as the app is usually served from a local IP address.

If you are accessing the API through your website, it would be wise to follow [@tamrat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65686920/4721369).